# Cannot load mod_perl.so into server after migrating from apache 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: apache, perl

After migrating from apache 2.2 to 2.4 can't load perl module

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 211 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax 
error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/perl.load: Cannot load 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so into server: 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror
```

Apache is compiled on ubuntu 12.04. libapache2-mod-perl2-2.0.5-5ubuntu1 is installled on the system.

Answer (score 2):

mod_perl needs binary compatibility with both the current versions of Apache *and* Perl.  If you have upgraded *either* then you need to upgrade / recompile mod_perl itself.

---

Of course going forward, you may want to consider a less fragile FCGI configuration.  Writing to a PSGI / Plack standard may help smooth any future change in this direction.

Extended discussion of the relative values of mod_perl / FCGI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009297/is-mod-perl-what-im-looking-for-fastcgi-psgi-plack/31010803#31010803).